# How to use a variable in the case field of switch statement?

Tags: c, switch-statement

Even though the switch syntax is not accepting variables for case labels are there any workarounds to perform similar operation instead of the plain old if-else comparison ?

Comment: if you only need a simple value you could use a sequence of ternary operators, but that's really a bad idea. Anyway, an else-if chain isn't any longer than a switch if your cases would be short, and if they're are made by a lot of statement you should break them in many lines anyway, so... what's the benefit?

Comment: What exactly is your use case for wanting to use a variable as a label in a switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually to work-around this I use a struct and function pointers, with only one if.

Untested example, just to have an idea of what I'm talking about:

```
#include "cases_functions.h"

typedef struct s_switch
{
  char* value;
  void (*do)(void);
} t_switch;

t_switch cases[] =
{
  {"add", add},
  {"sub", sub},
  {"divide", div},
  {0, 0}
};

void personal_switch(char *what)
{
  int i = 0;

  while (cases[i].value)
  {
    if (strcmp(cases[i].value, what) == 0)
      cases[i].do();
    i++;
  }
}
```

With this, you can change during runtime your different cases, add new ones and so on...
Of course, the selection method is free and you can for example have just an `int` and test with `==`, or more complex things.

Comment: I suppose you could make this elegant, by adding a comparison method as a function pointer, and by writing the actual search algorithm as a separate algorithm. And if we scratch our heads for a moment, we'd find out that we would merely be re-inventing the standard C function `bsearch` :)  Which may or may not be overkill, depending on the number of cases.

Comment: Never used this function! Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use enum.

```
enum my_enum {
    element1,
    element2
};

my_enum var;
switch(var)
{
    case element1:
    case element2:
}
```

It can be usefull for day in week for example

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this in my experience is to use lookup tables.

You can make it simple, which would be an index lookup table. That will only work with ints, and only adjacent ints 0 -> n.

Or you can make it generic, which is a complex implementation, but gives you the ability to use any form of "cases": they don't have to be adjacent integers, and they don't even have to be integers at all (could be floats, strings, whatever).

I'll give an example of the generic version (not tested). This example uses binary search, so the access time will be deterministic, and optimal if the number of cases are many.

```
// declare a custom search key for the foo object, could be any type
typedef int foo_key_t; 

// declare the actual data object:
typedef void(*foo_func_t)(void);
typedef enum
{
  const foo_key_t   key;
  foo_func_t        foo_func; // things to do when this "case" is found
} foo_t;


// a comparison function for objects of type foo_t
int foo_comp (const void* obj1, const void* obj2)
{
  const foo_t* f1 = obj1;
  const foo_t* f2 = obj2;

  return f1->key - f2->key;
}

---

// declare a "good to have" enum with a list of indices 
// indices are guaranteed to be adjacent numbers 0 -> n
typedef enum  
{
  FOO_FOO,
  FOO_BAR
  FOO_N // number of items in this enum
} foo_index_t;

// define a list of variables corresponding to the above enum
const foo_t foo [FOO_N] =  // a list sorted in adjacent search key order:
{
  { 123, &foo_func },
  { 456, &bar_func }
};

---

const foo_t* result;

result = bsearch(456,           // search for this "case"
                 foo,           // in the table foo
                 FOO_N,         // with this many objects
                 sizeof(foo_t), // with this object size
                 foo_comp);     // use this comparison function

if(result != NULL)
{
  result.foo_func();
}
else
{
  // this equals "default" in a switch-case.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "labels" are constants you could define macros...

```
#define FOO 1
#define BAR(x) (2*x)

switch (var)
{
    case FOO:    // foo
    case BAR(3): // bar
}
```

Maybe you could define some weird macro to get what you want, but it's easier to write a simple if-else-if chain, and I don't think it's a good idea to write and use complicated macros if you don't really need them.

Comment: That's a very complicated way to write `case 1:`  `case 6:`

Comment: FOO doesn't need to be always 1, that's why constant exists, to avoid magic numbers in the code, that's just an easy example. Thinking this way, we should never use defines in C, right? Those are the only true constants that C offers, with enums, but I find macros more clear to understand if constants are unrelated...